# Apache rewrite - match query string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I understand that using rewrites in apache if i want to match the query string then i should use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}
```

Which is fine, however, I have a csv with around 2000 urls to rewrite, a lot contain random query strings.  It will be a painstaking process to go through each and create the rule.

Is there any generic way to have the rewrite look at the entire url, including the query string and redirect it?

Comment: Don't do the rewriting on http server level, but move it up into some scripting language, for example php. Then you can simply convert the CSV data into a dictionary array and rewrite requests using the `header()` function. Comes out exactly the same, but you have much more flexibility and a much more convenient language.

Comment: Would there not be any performance issues, loading a csv, matching etc on every request for 2000 rewrite rules?

Comment: As said above: you convert the CSV into a dictionary array, indeed you do that _once_. After that it is static code. Obviously you do not want to parse the file again for each request.

Answer (score 0):

try `rewritemap`

example config for vurtual host

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap mymap "txt:/path/to/map.txt"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond ${mymap:%1} >""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${mymap:%1} [L]
```

and map.txt example

```
p=1&i=1 /test.php?n=2
p=1&i=2 /test.php?n=4
p=1&i=3 /test.php?n=6
...
```

Suppose that it is suitable for site with no hign load :)